# Delphi 2007 post-build event, copy exe into specific directory?

Tags: delphi, post-build-event

In Delphi 2007 how can I copy the newly-built exe into a specific directory using the post-build event?

Any link to a list of build event commands would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `copy` command in your post-build event:

```
copy "$(OUTPUTPATH)" MyFolder
```

The `$(OUTPUTPATH)` expands to the output file's full path.

Comment: Can I make this generic by using outputdir or outputname? I cn never remember the difference!

Comment: Yep, I added what you need. Doesn't your IDE list the available macros?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to quote source and destination? There could be spaces in either of those paths.